# SQL Query to SELECT from multiple Schema's

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an database with alot of users (schema's) for example:

- user_1
- user_2
- user_3
- ...
- user_303

All of those got the same tables, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `viewed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `forId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fromId` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`, `content`, `date`, `viewed`, `forId`, `fromId`) VALUES
(1, 'Hello World', '2020-06-04 14:49:17', 1, 2106, 1842),
(2, 'Hi there', '2020-06-04 14:49:39', 1, 2106, 1842),
(3, 'test 1', '2022-01-03 11:40:43', 1, 3006, 3006),
(4, 'Test 2', '2022-01-20 12:01:52', 1, 1842, 1842);
```

What I want is a query for example:

```
USE user_1, user_2, user_3;

SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `content` LIKE `%Hi%`;
```

I don't know if this is possible as a SQL Query, an other option is to write a small PHP code with a for each loop but than I want a command so I get an list of all users: `user_1 till user_303`

The users are not from 1 till 303 there are some users deleted, to it can be that `user_200` doesn't exist any more.

Hope someone here can help me out

Comment: You should have one common messages table - for all users.

Comment: I agree with jarlh, add a user attribute to messages and use one table for all messages. That said, you can get the schemas as `select table_schema from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'MESSAGES'` and either loop over that or create a union query.

Comment: *I have an database with alot of users (schema's)* Do you mean that there is a lot of users, and each user uses its own separate database? *I don't know if this is possible* No, this is impossible. But you may access the tables from different databases in the query, like: `SELECT * FROM db1.table UNION ALL SELECT * FROM db2.table;`.

Comment: A qualified table name can include the schema eg user_1.messages, user_2.messages etc you don't have to switch schemas to do this..If the number of schemas is prone to change for flexibility dynamic sql would help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: This is a really bad DB design, so it is a lot better to spend a time modifying your design and then the query will be really easy

Comment: This is just an example, my bad there are schemas like client_1 till client_303 and those clients can have users and those users can send messages to each other. `SELECT * FROM client_1.messages, client_2.messages, client_3.messages, client_4.messages` etc. etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to write the query you want.

```
USE information_schema;

SELECT concat("SELECT * FROM ", table_schema,".",table_name, " UNION ALL ") 
FROM tables WHERE table_name = 'messages';
```

You will obtain something like this;

> SELECT * FROM base.messages UNION ALL
> SELECT * FROM c.messages UNION ALL

You can then run this query to obtain what you want.

Comment: Yes now I get an list of 238 rows as return, but without content/values...

Comment: You have to run the result as query next.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can concatenate only 2 arguments, so you have to use nesting to concatenate more than two arguments.
Also you should use ALL_TABLES instead of information_schema

```
SELECT
    concat('SELECT MESSAGE FROM ', concat(OWNER, concat('.', concat(TABLE_NAME, ' UNION ALL '))))
FROM
    ALL_TABLES
WHERE
    OWNER LIKE 'user_%';
```

Don't forget to delete the last UNION ALL from result.

Comment: Please format the code properly and explain it.